# Referencing a class that is not instantiated / does not yet exist

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, abstract-class

I have a Winforms application that is designed to integrate with external software packages. This application reads data from these packages and pushes it to our server where users log in and use our application (App).

```
public abstract ClassToImplement
{
    public abstract void DefinedMethod1();
    public abstract void DefinedMethod2();
}
```

When we designed the application it was intended to do 95% of the integration work with the remaining 5% (implementation class / App2) being developed by a consultant who's familiar with the 3rd party software.

```
public class Implemented : ClassToImplement{
    public override void DefinedMethod1(...);
    public override void DefinedMethod2(...);
}
```

The "App" outputs a Class Library which is then referenced in the Implementation (App2). In our design we created an Abstract Class and defined the methods. The idea was that the consultant would download the repo for the implementation class and include the App as a reference. They would then write the necessary code for the methods they're implementing, compile and "voila!"

For obvious reasons I don't want to share the source project with external developers, otherwise I'd just share the full solution and use a single app, and, while I know they can see a lot with the DLL reference, it is just easier for us to control everything.

The problem comes with App: the main application algorithm needs to instantiate the implementation class and then the program runs perfectly.

in Form1.cs of App:

```
ClassToImplement impObj = new Implemented();
impObj.DefinedMethod1();
impObj.DefinedMethod2();
```

The challenge I'm having is that I cannot build "App" to output a DLL without instantiating the Class. I cannot instantiate the Implemented Class as I haven't got the code (yet).

It would be great to know how to go about achieving this sort of abstraction with a dependancy on (yet) unwritten code and also, what is the technical term for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: How about using an interface instead of a abstract class?

Comment: @thehennyy I'm not averse to doing so, how would that solve the instantiation issue? Could you please share a help resource or answer using my code example? I'm happy to try a different approach

Comment: @MineR Are you suggesting that App2 then somehow "overrides" the blank implementation? Do you have an example or article that covers this so that I can get an idea of the approach?

Comment: @Daniel I misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it just "work" use a Func which returns an instance of the abstract class.

**In your secret repo:**

```
//Your "App" DLL Project
public abstract class ClassToImplement
{
    public abstract void DefinedMethod1();
    public abstract void DefinedMethod2();
}


public class App : Form
{

    public App(Func<ClassToImplement> initiator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ClassToImplement ci = initiator.Invoke();
        ci.DefinedMethod1();
        ci.DefinedMethod2();
    }
}


//This is in a separate project which will be your startup project internally

public class Dummy : ClassToImplement
{
    public override void DefinedMethod1(){}
    public override void DefinedMethod2(){}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new App(()=> new Dummy()));
    }
}
```

**In the repo shared with the consultant:**

```
// In the repo which is shared with the consultant
// This will be the startup project on the build server, and when the consultant is testing.
public class Implementation : ClassToImplement
{
    public override void DefinedMethod1(){}
    public override void DefinedMethod2(){}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new App(()=> new Implementation()));
    }
}
```

On your build server, you can pull from both the repos, and set the startup project as the one given to the consultant. But when you are testing and developing internally, you set the startup project to your version with an implementation that does nothing.

*As a side note, if you think what you are doing needs to be protected from consultants who have signed a confidentiality agreement, make sure to obfuscate when you do a release.*

Comment: This approach looks great except that, after refactoring to implement this suggestion, I get the error "Non-invocable member 'Implementation' cannot be used like a method." Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It's a syntax error - if you post the code, it will be clear.

Comment: You were right, my bad, thank you, it seems like it's working, just running tests

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-step process usually:

1. Locate and load the assembly/dll:

   ```
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(DLL);
   ```
2. Instantiate the implemented class:

   ```
   Type type = assembly.GetType(FullNameOfImplemented);
   AppInstance = (ClassToImplement)Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
   ```

Comment: Thank you, Amit. In other answers I did format code successfully. I was frustrated for long minutes trying and failing.

Answer (score 0):

The process you are looking for is often called [stubbing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceStub.html). In this case you've chosen to encapsulate the integration functionality in a library, not web services, but the principle is the same.

> The idea was that the consultant would download the repo for the implementation class and include the App as a reference.

This sounds like you've got the dependency relationship the wrong way round. If the consultant's code references your app, then your app can't reference it - it'd be a circular dependency. Instead, factor your app something more in line with the following:

`App
|
|
App.Integration.Contracts
^ ^
| |
| App.Integration.Stub
|
App.Integration`

The abstract class - it could just as easily be an interface in C# - resides in the Contracts assembly. This is the only compiled dependency your application has. Then *at runtime* use configuration to load either the stub, or the full implementation using an IoC container. An example is [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) for which you will need its [configuration API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1100000/Unity-Framework-with-ASP-NET-using-Config-Files-an). Reference the true type to use in the configuration file and change *only that* to update your application to use the full functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, this sounds along the lines of what we're trying to achieve and your point about a circular dependancy is very true. Taking all that you've mentioned into account, if the main logic resides in the app and the methods that are required derive from the `App.Integration.Stub` which are inherited from the `App.Integration` how would I instantiate to build the DLL that the consultant requires? Is this what the Unity framework will do? Forgive my ignorance, I'm not accustomed to this level of abstraction

Comment: Yes, it's the IoC container's responsibility to instantiate the dependency. Ideally you would make `ClassToImplement` a constructor dependency of a Form, or of a dependency of a Form, and the IoC container would implicitly understand, assuming the type is registered, that it has to instantiate the derived type. At a push you can wrap the container in a static class that calls `Resolve<T>()`, but this is known as [service locator](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) which is not preferred by some people, but if you understand its limitations it's not *bad* per se.

Answer (score 0):

First off I think you need to implement a proper plugin system if you dont want to share your code with that other developers.

Second you should code against your interface and not against its implementation. First because you dont have it and second because you may want to switch implementations for different 3rd party software.

If you need an instance for testing or stuff, you can use a handwritten mock or an mocking framework. If you need a real instance later on (when the other developers have delivered) you can use some design pattern like factory pattern or others for the creation. Try to avoid the new keyword if you want to change implementations later on.